# Entity Framework - list (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
};

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author? author { get; set; }
};
```

I have code similar to this, can I assign in author controller list of books to author.Books or it's property only for relation?

For example

```
author.Books = await _context.Books.Where(b => b.AuthorId == Id).ToListAsync();
```

It's correct code or create NotMapped property?

Comment: Many times it is answered in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can get books with author query and there is no need to make a new one to get books

by using `Include()` like this :

```
 var author=await _context.Author.Include(a=>a.books).ToListAsync()
```